# How can I use C (sem_t) threads one by one

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

I tried to use C (sem_t) threads one by one but but when using lock the loop always continues on a single thread.I thought the problem was to use only 2 threads and the threads were very fast, but when I used 10 threads, I saw that threads get involved but still output 3-4 times in a row.

Here is my thread function

Here is my main function

Here is my call to run on my ubuntu terminal

```
--------and--------
```

Here is my output

Here is my expected output

By the way, the code works exactly as how I want it, except for this problem.

Comment: Where is the `sem_post(&t2);` call?

Comment: I use t2 as counter it starts with with value of nOP and decreasing with each cycle thats why I did not use sem_post

Comment: You have to pair the `sem_wait/sem_post` calls or it will block. For a counter, consider using `stdatomic.h` primitives instead. Even without `t2` you have a race condition/thread starvation. Simplifying: `while (1) { sem_wait(&t); do_stuff(); sem_post(&t); }` Assume taskA gets the semaphore first and then taskB does `sem_wait`. When taskA does `sem_post` on iteration 1, it _immediately_ does `sem_wait` on iteration 2. So, which task proceeds? Probably taskA. There is no guarantee that taskB will ever get the semaphore. It _may_ win the race once in a while but not the fairness you want.

Comment: Yes you right but after "sem_wait(&t2)" I locked the thread so there is no way other thread   do some operation right ? Is there a possiblity that other thread can operate "sem_wait(&t2)" through lock ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my top comments:

You have to pair the `sem_wait/sem_post` calls or it will block. For a counter, consider using `stdatomic.h` primitives instead.

Even without `t2` you have a race condition/thread starvation. Simplifying: `while (1) { sem_wait(&t); do_stuff(); sem_post(&t); }`

Assume taskA gets the semaphore first and then taskB does `sem_wait`. When taskA does `sem_post` on iteration 1, it *immediately* does `sem_wait` on iteration 2. So, which task proceeds? Probably taskA. There is no guarantee that taskB will ever get the semaphore. It may win the race once in a while but not the fairness you want.

> Yes you right but after "sem_wait(&t2)" I locked the thread so there is no way other thread do some operation right? Is there a possiblity that other thread can operate "sem_wait(&t2)" through lock? – Eren Berk Saltaş

As I mentioned in my comments, using a semaphore is *not* the best way to implement a shared decrementing iteration counter.

Using `atomic_fetch_add` can achieve the same effect cleanly. Or, just do the decrement inside the locked critical section.

---

With all the various [debug] `printf` and doing `fopen / fprintf / fclose`, you're not going to get very good timing results.

That is, we're measuring a system with `printf` and *not* the real system. So, the pauses for I/O will mask the thread starvation issue.

Depending upon your real application, you may have more work to do to achieve fairness and prevent thread starvation.

---

Here's a refactored version of the code. Since you didn't post your full code, I had to synthesize variable definitions and `main`, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

sem_t t;
sem_t t2;
pthread_mutex_t mtx;

#define MAXITER     10000
#if USEATOMIC
int counter;
#else
volatile int counter;
#endif

#define MAXTASK     2
pthread_t tsklist[MAXTASK];

void *
run(void *args)
{
    int val = 1;
    long thridx = (long) args;

    printf("Hello There! thread  kthread ID - %ld\n", thridx);
#if 0
    sem_getvalue(&t2, &val);
#endif

    while (val > 0) {
        printf("%ld: LOOPTOP val=%d\n", thridx, val);

        sem_wait(&t);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);

// NOTE/BUG: this will block a 2nd task forever
#if 0
        sem_wait(&t2);
        sem_getvalue(&t2, &val);
#endif

        printf("%ld: LOCKED\n", thridx);

        double r = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX * 20.0 - 10.0;
        double r2 = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX * 4.0 - 2.0;

        if (r < 0 && r2 < 0) {
            FILE *fp = fopen("f.out", "a");
            fprintf(fp, "%lf ---- %lf\n", r, r2);
            fclose(fp);
        }
        else if (r > 0 && r2 < 0) {
            FILE *fp = fopen("f2.out", "a");
            fprintf(fp, "%lf ---- %lf\n", r, r2);
            fclose(fp);

        }
        else if (r > 0 && r2 > 0) {
            FILE *fp = fopen("f3.out", "a");
            fprintf(fp, "%lf ---- %lf\n", r, r2);
            fclose(fp);
        }
        else if (r < 0 && r2 > 0) {
            FILE *fp = fopen("f4.out", "a");
            fprintf(fp, "%lf ---- %lf\n", r, r2);
            fclose(fp);
        }
        else {
            FILE *fp = fopen("f5.out", "a");
            fprintf(fp, "%lf ---- %lf\n", r, r2);
            fclose(fp);
        }

#if ! USEATOMIC
        val = --counter;
#endif

        sem_post(&t);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

#if USEATOMIC
        val = atomic_fetch_add(&counter,-1);
#endif
    }

// NOTE/BUG: this aborts _all_ threads
#if 0
    exit(0);
#else
    return (void *) 0;
#endif
}

int
main(void)
{

    sem_init(&t,0,1);
    sem_init(&t2,0,1);

    pthread_mutex_init(&mtx,NULL);

#if USEATOMIC
    atomic_store(&counter,MAXITER);
#else
    counter = MAXITER;
#endif

    for (long idx = 0;  idx < MAXTASK;  ++idx)
        pthread_create(&tsklist[idx],NULL,run,(void *) idx);

    for (long idx = 0;  idx < MAXTASK;  ++idx)
        pthread_join(tsklist[idx],NULL);

    int val = atomic_load(&counter);
    printf("counter=%d\n",counter);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This one not directly answer my question but I get some knowledge from it thx